# Javascript Selenium: Variable set to undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium

In the following code, testEmail is a global variable within a file. I am using selenium-webdriver. Console.log(testEmail) does display the correct email, however, when I attempt to pass this parameter to a function in another file, it is immediately set to undefined. Why is this? The function the parameter is passed to returns a promise.

```
  test.it('should get confirmation email in under 1 minute', function() {
    this.timeout(0);
    console.log("Test Email:" + testEmail);
    return imapGmail.checkNewestEmail(testEmail);
  }
```

Comment: can you please post your full code ? I am not sure how are you setting your `global testEmail` variable

Comment: The full code is about 1000 lines long. Basically, at the top of the file I have `var testEmail = "testEmail" + now + "@gmail.com".` Like I said, the testEmail prints fine when `console.log("Test Email:" + testEmail);` is executed.

Comment: post your error message